# Add offset to a function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, offset, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the waypoint plugin and need help to modify the offset.

Where do I add **offset: '25%'** ? Link: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/

```
$.ajax({
    url: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        $('.element').waypoint(function(direction) 
            {
            if (direction === 'down') {
            alert('Alert notification')
            this.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can read the specs you should be able to pass an object of options like:

```
    $('.element').waypoint({
        offset: "25%",
        handler:function(direction){
            if (direction === 'down') {
              alert('Alert notification')
              this.destroy();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check this page http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/, it says to pass an object. Use the handler method to trigger your alert.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
      element: document.getElementById('number-offset-negative'),
      handler: function(direction) {
        notify('25px past the top')
      },
      offset: -25
    })
```